# Are all boiler heating systems closed?

Tags: water-heater, boiler

Are all boiler heating systems closed?  In other words, are they all filled with water that is just constantly recirculated, or are there some that put the outgoing water elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, No. For 99% of house-heating boiler systems that heat water-filled radiators or underfloor water-pipes. (Statistics invented according to Intertube tradition) modulo relief valves, header tanks.

Comment: I agree that 99% of boiler systems are closed, for some values of 99%.

Comment: Where do you suppose the "outgoing" water would be sent?  I can only think of one place... which would be the hot water faucets... so, no, they're not all closed.  Some are dual-purpose, providing potable "domestic hot water" and space heat.  At least in 1% of cases, according to the previous 2 comments. :)

Comment: Good question.  I guess I had in mind that the water would recirculate when not in use (such as at a tap) but could also be provided to a tap when needed.  Thanks for the answers!